# c# SOAP Request With Attachment

Tags: c#, soap, attachment

I have the task of cumsuming a 3rd partys' SOAP webservice using C#.
Now usually I would generate the classes from the WSDL and create a client and call the method.  Relatively straightforward right.
However, this one has me pretty confused as it specifies in their docs that it requires an attachment specified in the details element.
When creating the classes from the WSDL, the "details" declaration is as....

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="anyURI", IsNullable=true, Order=13)]
public string Details
```

It would seem that "Details" needs to identify the attachment to include in the request, that makes sense, but how to add the attachment?
I thought I could do some preliminary investigations with SOAP UI using MTOM but that is not yeilding any success yet.

Of course, an example would be great but I want to grasp what's actually going on so if anyone has any pointers on this to allow me to work the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the anonymised documentation I have to go on.

```
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <abc:abdReq>
        <def:reqinfo>
        <jkl:field1>12345</jkl:field1>
        <hkl:field2>ABC</jkl:field2>
        <jkl:field3>XYZ</jkl:field3>
        </def:reqinfo>
    <ghi:Details>cid:12345678</ghi:Details>
    </abc:abdReq>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The attached document is also XML and the docs specify the below as the header of that....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in this instance I was making a mountain out of a molehill.
Once I managed to do a successful test with SOAP UI I used the following article (kudos to Travis and the longevity of relevance) to assist me.

Excluding the headers, I simply wrote the whole contents of the raw request into the request stream of a HttpWebRequest and made the request.